# How to show child frame in callback (in the define block)

Tags: user-interface, lambda, scheme, racket

I have two windows. Main Window and Help window. I want the Help window to show up when a user presses a button.

```lisp
(define help_window (new frame%
  [label "Help"]
  [parent main_window]
  [min-height 400] ;so window size is not 0
  [min-width 400])
)

(define (help)
  (send help_window show #true)) ; 

(define help_button (new button% [parent panel]
  [label "Help"]
  [callback (lambda (button event) help)] )
)
```

My problem is that if I do `(define (help) (...))` then nothing works. I click the button and it doesn't show up.

I tried `(define help (...))` and the definition executes before the button click and makes the window show up behind the main window.

I am not even sure I should be using a lambda. The tutorials have it in there, and I couldn't get the program to compile by calling any other function than a lambda. Also, without the `(button event)` being passed to the called function I'm not even sure what a callback would be defined as. Actually, I have no idea what lambda does with `(button event)` or whether the function call does anything with `(button event)`.

---

If I try `[callback help]` with the `(define (help) ... )` function I get an error:

```
initialization for button%: contract violation
expected: (procedure-arity-includes/c 2)
given: #<procedure:syntax_help>
```

If I try `[callback (help)]` with the `(define (help) ... )` function I get an error:

```
initialization for button%: contract violation
expected: (procedure-arity-includes/c 2)
given: #<void>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about this UI framework, but it sure looks like you want

```
(lambda (button event) (help))
```

`help` is a function, so to make it do anything you need to call it. You can't just use `help` itself as the callback, because that takes zero arguments, but callbacks must take two. This is why you've created a lambda, to take two arguments (`button` and `event`), then ignore them and call `help` with no arguments.

Comment: Oh. Thanks! The Racket tutorials don't explain this.

Comment: @Ryan: which tutorials are you talking about? Where do you think could be improved to make things more clear?

Comment: Just the ones linked from the Intro tutorial (go to racket-lang.org). Hover cursor over bottom left block on front page.